# Can I create a view that divides every few rows with a different value?

Tags: mysql, view

Essentially, I have a table with *daily* currency conversion rates in relation to currency A, and I want to provide a view with rates in relation to currency B.

My table has three columns (with associated types) besides an auto-incrementing id: `date (date)`, `currency (varchar(3))`, and `conversion_rate (decimal(16, 6))`. Let's say it looks like this:

```
| date       | currency | rate_to_A |
| 2014-11-22 | D        | 4.00000   |
| 2014-11-22 | B        | 0.50000   |
| 2014-11-21 | D        | 5.00000   |
| 2014-11-21 | B        | 0.25000   |
```

For a specific date, I can produce a select query that switches the currency:

```sql
SELECT date,
    currency, 
    (conversion_rate / (SELECT conversion_rate FROM currency_rates_to_A WHERE date='2014-11-20' AND currency='B')) AS rate_to_B 
FROM currency_rates_to_A 
WHERE date='2014-11-20';
```

But what I need, is a view that can do the same for ALL dates (ie, all the data in the original table). Something like the following:

```
| date       | currency | rate_to_B |
| 2014-11-22 | D        | 8.00000   | -- 4.00000 / 0.50000
| 2014-11-22 | B        | 1.00000   | -- 0.50000 / 0.50000
| 2014-11-21 | D        | 20.00000  | -- 5.00000 / 0.25000
| 2014-11-22 | B        | 1.00000   | -- 0.25000 / 0.25000
```

The problem is that each row needs to be divided with that date's B rate, which has the same date, and the value 'B' in the `currency` column.

Is that at all possible?

Comment: But this is my use case. What kind of simple example do you have in mind? EDIT: The comment I replied to was deleted.

Comment: "Hello, this is what I have, this is what I want, and this is what I tried" - that kind of example.

Comment: But that's exactly what I tried to write :-/ I have that exact table, I want to create the view I described, and my only, unsuccessful try to get it is that query. I'm not sure how to make it simpler.

Comment: I'll try to express what I want in an example.

Comment: See how much better that was?

Comment: Yup, thanks for the nudge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is quite close.  You just need to change the subquery to a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT cr.*, 
       (conversion_rate / (SELECT cr2.conversion_rate
                           FROM currency_rates_to_A cr2
                           WHERE cr2.date = cr.date AND currency = 'B'
                          )
         ) AS rate_to_B 
FROM currency_rates_to_A cr;
```

You can also do this with an explicit `self join`:

```
SELECT cr.*, cr.conversion_rate / cr2.conversion_rate as rate_to_B
FROM currency_rates_to_A cr JOIN
     currency_rates_to_A cr2
     ON cr2.date = cr.date AND cr2.currency = 'B';
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understand correctly (an example table input & output could have helped), but generally speaking you could do a parameterized nested select, however it's better to use a join.
Maybe something like:

```
select a1.date, a1.currency, a1.rate/a2.rate
from currency_rate_to_A a1 currency_rate_to_A a2
on a1.date=a2.date and a2.currency='b'
```

You might need to tweak it if I missed something in the logic, apologies in advance.

Comment: You missed nothing! I'll accept the other answer, since both are correct, and that one was quicker. But thanks, anyway!